# application that is created with MFC Visual Studio 2010 on Windows XP 32 bits, crashes?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, windows-xp

I created application with MFC Visual Studio 2010 on Windows XP 32 bits. Also, I created an installer, the installer installs the application on different Windows OS  (window 7 with 64 bits and windows xp with 32 bits) correctly. The application works fine on Windows 7 64 bits, but crashes on windows xp 32 bits.

Note: 
The windows 7 with 64 bit installer uses the 32 bit dlls, and install the application in Program files(x86). 
The Windows Xp with 32 bits installer uses the 32 bits dlls and install the application in program files.

any idea why the application crashes on XP?

Comment: Are you also distributing the mfc libraries (if you are not statically linking to MFC)? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235264(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: yes, I installed the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)

Comment: that was just a guess. you'll need to provide more detail in the form of a crash dump, error message or something.

Comment: Currently, I am avoiding this crash by including the following dlls in same folder as the .exe file: